# Rock Paper Scissors - How to store the user choice and compare it to the cpu choice

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/Sergiu18/0rzL6yko/10/

So far I created the click event which console logs what the user chose, and a random function which console logs what the computer chose. I do not know how to store the user choice in order to compare it with what the CPU chose.

I thought about using if statement

if(randomNumber === 1 && let's say that the user chose rock) {

alert("It is a tie")

}

and so on.

I would create an if statement for each scenario, and then I would alert the result. I know I would repeat myself, but it is easier for me at the moment to create something which I understand. What I want to find out is how do I create the "let's say that the user chose rock" part. I thought about creating a variable userChoice, but I am not sure how to connect it with the choice the user made. I know about this.innerHTML, but I am not sure if it can be used here somehow.

```
// User Choice
var rockUser = document.querySelector("#rock");

var paperUser = document.querySelector("#paper");

var scissorsUser = document.querySelector("#scissors");

var userChoice; 

rockUser.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("You chose Rock!");
})

paperUser.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("You chose Paper!");
})

scissorsUser.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("You chose Scissors!");
})

// CPU Choice
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *3) +1;

if(randomNumber == 1) {
console.log("CPU chose Rock!");
} else if(randomNumber == 2 ) {
console.log("CPU chose Paper!");
} else if(randomNumber == 3) {
console.log("CPU chose Scissors");
}

//Comparing the two
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "connect it with the choice the user made"? Do you want to display something in the UI whether he won/lost?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic function similar to the following:

In your HTML, define one empty tag

```
<div id="computerChoice"></div>
```

```
const mapping = {
   1: "CPU chose Rock!",
   2: "CPU chose Paper!",
   3: "CPU chose Scissors"
};

console.log(mapping[randomNumber]);
document.getElementById("computerChoice").innerText = mapping[randomNumber];

function getWinner(cpuChoice, userChoice){
    //Compare logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Enum = {
    ROCK: 0,
    PAPER: 1,
    SCISSORS: 2,
    LIZARD: 3,
    SPOCK: 4,
};

const Names = [
    'Rock',
    'Paper',
    'Scissors',
    'Lizard',
    'Spock',
];

const Winner = {
    NOBODY: 0,
    ONE: 1,
    TWO: 2,
};

const WinnerNames = [
    'Nobody',
    'You',
    'Bot',
];

function oneOrTwo(one, two) {
    const match = [
        (two === Enum.PAPER) + (two === Enum.SPOCK),
        (two === Enum.SCISSORS) + (two === Enum.LIZARD),
        (two === Enum.ROCK) + (two === Enum.SPOCK),
        (two === Enum.ROCK) + (two === Enum.SCISSORS),
        (two === Enum.PAPER) + (two === Enum.LIZARD),
    ];
    return match[one] + Winner.ONE - (one === two);
}

rockUser.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const botChose = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
  console.log("You chose Rock, Bot chose " + Names[botChose]);
  console.log("Winner is : " + WinnerNames[oneOrTwo(Enum.ROCK, botChose)]);
})

paperUser.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const botChose = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
  console.log("You chose Paper, Bot chose " + Names[botChose]);
  console.log("Winner is : " + WinnerNames[oneOrTwo(Enum.PAPER, botChose)]);
})

scissorsUser.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const botChose = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
  console.log("You chose Scissors, Bot chose " + Names[botChose]);
  console.log("Winner is : " + WinnerNames[oneOrTwo(Enum.SCISSORS, botChose)]);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1q704hg/4/